# SharePoint 2013: Unable to Update newly Created Item in a Different List - Error "Coercion Failed..."

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

Scenario: I have 2 lists. Lets say List 1 & List 2.

I am trying to:

1. In List 1 Workflow, I Create a New List Item on List 2. This works file. I see an empty List Item in List 2 as soon as I create an entry in List 1.
2. In List 1 Workflow, now that I have created a New List Item on List 2, I am attempting to Copy the Fields over from List 1 to List 2.

This is where I get the Error

> Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type.

Once the New Item is created via "Create Item In..." List Action, it gives me a variable: "Create"

This variable contains the Item ID of the newly Created Item in List 2.

I am using this variable: "Create" to Update this newly created item.

But I get the above error.

[image: Setup]

Comment: are you trying to write into the ID column?

Comment: No Gwny. I need to write other columns such as Change Number, Status, Description. I'm using ID as the key column to write these entries.

Comment: what type is the create Variable of?